# Gulp is not updating my static generated pages with Assemble

Tags: node.js, gulp, handlebars.js, spacebars, assemble

I have a working Modular Gulpfile which is building my static pages with assemble. So far so good. When i run a watch job and change my data in a Json file the watcher is running assemble again, building the pages without the new data. Handlebars partials and all other things are working exept for the data files. When i quit my watch task and run the whole assemble task again, the data **is** updated, so the assemble task works i think.

This is my assemble task.

```
module.exports = function(gulp, plugins, config, assemble, browserSync) {
var error = require("./error.js");
var clean = require("./clean-html.js");
//var production = require("./distribution.js");
var app = assemble();

gulp.task('load', function() {
    app.partials(config.source.assembleSrc.partials);
    app.layouts(config.source.assembleSrc.layouts);
    app.data(config.source.assembleSrc.data);
});

gulp.task('assemble', ['load'], function() {
    return app.src(config.source.assembleSrc.pages)
        .pipe(plugins.plumber({
            errorHandler: error
        })) //Added proper error handling
        .pipe(app.renderFile())
        .pipe(plugins.rename(function(path) {
            path.extname = ".html" // Rename to HTML
        }))
        .pipe(plugins.if(production, gulp.dest(config.dist.html), gulp.dest(config.temp.html)))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        })); // Browser reload


});
```

};

Thanx in advance!

Comment: Are you using the latest version of assemble? There was a bug in one of the dependencies where it was using `require` to load `json` files. `require` caches calls to a path if it was already loaded. We've fixed that since then, so it shouldn't be cached now. If you're using the latest version of assemble, then there's probably a bug and it would be a good idea to open an issue on the assemble repository.

Comment: yeah that json bug was over a year ago as I recall.

Comment: Allright, thanx for the answers. Should i open an issue? Or is it a bug from a while ago like johnschlinkert says?